# What is the difference between emit and emitSource with LiveData ? ( as in REAL time USE-CASE )

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack, kotlin-coroutines

`emit` accepts the `data` class whereas `emitSource` accepts `LiveData<T>` ( T -> `data` ). Considering the following example :- I have two type of calls :-

```
suspend fun getData(): Data // returns directly data
```

and the other one ;

```
suspend fun getData(): LiveData<Data> // returns live data instead
```

For the first case i can use:-

```
liveData {
   emit(LOADING)
   emit(getData())
}
```

My question : Using the above method would solve my problem , **WHY** do we need `emitSource(liveData)` anyway ?

> Any good use-case for using the `emitSource` method would make it clear !

Comment: Most likely has to do with the scenarios where you'd want to use `Transformations.switchMap` or a MediatorLiveData.

Answer (score 34):

As you mentioned, I don't think it solves anything in your stated problem, but I usually use it like this:

If I want to show cached data to the user from the db while I get fresh data from remote, with only emit it would look something like this:

```
liveData{
    emit(db.getData())
    val latest = webService.getLatestData()
    db.insert(latest)
    emit(db.getData())
}
```

But with emitSource it looks like this:

```
liveData{
    emitSource(db.getData())
    val latest = webService.getLatestData()
    db.insert(latest)
}
```

Don't need to call emit again since the liveData already have a source.

Comment: I couldn't get it for a while especially with the db scenario, putting both examples is perfect to understand!

Comment: What is LiveData *source* ?

Comment: @lons LiveData source means everywhere livedata gets it's value from it. In this example source is db.

Answer (score 15):

From what I understand `emit(someValue)` is similar to `myData.value = someValue` whereas `emitSource(someLiveValue)` is similar to `myData = someLiveValue`. This means that you can use emit whenever you want to set a value once, but if you want to connect your live data to another live data value you use emit source. An example would be emitting live data from a call to room (using `emitSource(someLiveData)`) then performing a network query and emitting an error (using `emit(someError)`).

Answer (score 10):

I found a real use-case which depicts the use of `emitSource` over `emit` which I have used many times in production now. :D The use-case:

Suppose u have some user data (`User` which has some fields like `userId`, `userName` ) returned by some `ApiService`.

The `User` Model:

```
data class User(var userId: String, var userName: String)
```

The `userName` is required by the view/activity to paint the UI. And the `userId` is used to make **another** API call which returns the `UserData` like `profileImage` , `emailId`.

The `UserData` Model:

```
data class UserData(var profileImage: String, var emailId: String)
```

This can be achieved internally using `emitSource` **by wiring the two liveData** in the `ViewModel` like:

`User` liveData -

```
val userLiveData: LiveData<User> = liveData {
   emit(service.getUser())
}
```

`UserData` liveData -

```
val userDataLiveData: LiveData<UserData> = liveData {
   emitSource(userLiveData.switchMap {
       liveData {
           emit(service.getUserData(it.userId))
       }
   })
}
```

So, in the activity / view one can **ONLY** call `getUser()` and the `getUserData(userId)` will be **automatically triggered** internally via `switchMap`.

You need not *manually* call the `getUserData(id)` by passing the id.

> This is a simple example, imagine there is a **chain of dependent-tasks** which needs to be executed one after the other, each of which is observed in the activity. `emitSource` comes in `handy`

Answer (score 8):

With **emitSource()** you can not only emit a single value, but attach your LiveData to another LiveData and start emitting from it. Anyway, each emit() or emitSource() call will remove the previously added source.

```
var someData = liveData {
    val cachedData = dataRepository.getCachedData()
    emit(cachedData)

    val actualData = dataRepository.getData()
    emitSource(actualData)
}
```

The activity that’s observing the someData object, will quickly receive the cached data on the device and update the UI. Then, the LiveData itself will take care of making the network request and replace the cached data with a new live stream of data, that will eventually trigger the Activity observer and update the UI with the updated info.

Source: [Exploring new Coroutines and Lifecycle Architectural Components integration on Android](https://medium.com/corouteam/exploring-kotlin-coroutines-and-lifecycle-architectural-components-integration-on-android-c63bb8a9156f)

Comment: But what about when changes are made to the cached data. How can we emit those ones next.

Answer (score 0):

I will like share a example where we use "**emit**" and "**emitsource**" both to communicate from UI -> View Model -> Repository

**Repository layer we use emit to send the values downstream** :

```
suspend fun fetchNews(): Flow<Result<List<Article>>> {
    val queryPath = QueryPath("tata", apikey = AppConstant.API_KEY)
    return flow {
        emit(
            Result.success(
                openNewsAPI.getResponse(
                    "everything",
                    queryPath.searchTitle,
                    queryPath.page,
                    queryPath.apikey
                ).articles
            )
        )
    }.catch { exception ->
        emit(Result.failure(RuntimeException(exception.message)));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel layer we use emitsource to pass the live data object to UI for subscriptions**

```
val loader = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

val newsListLiveData = liveData<Result<List<Article>>> {
    loader.postValue(true)
    emitSource(newRepo.fetchNews()
        .onEach {
            loader.postValue(false)
        }
        .asLiveData())
}
```

**UI Layer - we observe the live data emitted by emitsource**

```
 viewModel.newsListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { result ->
        val listArticle = result.getOrNull()
        if (result.isSuccess && listArticle != null) {
            setupList(binding.list, listArticle)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                appContext,
                result.exceptionOrNull()?.message + "Error",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    })
```

We convert Flow observable to LiveData in viewModel